# Algorithm for finding the longest path in a undirected weighted tree (positive weights)

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I'm trying to find from a undirected weighted tree of only positive weights the longest path (diameter of a tree, I'm told?) I know the most common algorithm is one where you pick a random node $x$, use DFS from that node to find the longest path which ends with node $y$ and once again from $y$ using DFS find the longest path which ends in $z$. $(y,z)$ should then be the longest path.

However, I was wondering if this another algorithm I thought of would work (and with the same complexity of $O(|V|)$

1. Find the longest edge in graph $e$
2. $e$ joins 2 nodes $a$ and $b$. Considering both $a$ and $b$ to be root of their respective subtrees, run DFS on both $a$ and $b$ and find the longest path $A$ and $B$ which end with the node $a_{end}$ and $b_{end}$ respectively.
3. $(a_{end}, b_{end})$ is the longest path.

My reason was the longest path of the graph has to contain the edge with the heaviest weighting. Is that a correct assumption? Also, the algorithm is still of complexity $O(|V|)$ since step 1. is $O(|V|)$, step 2 for DFS on $a$ is $O(|V|)$ and DFS on $b$ is $O(|V|)$. That probably isn't so efficient compared to the standard algorithm but it should adhere to the said requirements I guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is false, this is a counterexample:

[image]

Check, that the longest path (all black edges) has weight $6$, while any path containg the red edge has at most weight $5$.

Comment: Yea I kinda found a counterexample too to my algorithm a while after I posted. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @mercurial Tomas still answered your question. I think it would be polite to upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: @VedranŠego yea was going to do so directly after commenting but was told to wait a minute :)

Comment: Ah, bad timing on my side then. Took me a while to read it all, so whene there was still no green checkmark, I thought you forgot. I apologize for the mistake.

Comment: Well, thanks for the checkmark, you are rewarded with a better picture ;)